# SQL Update multiple rows in a single query

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

If let's say i would like to update 2 or more rows in a single SQL query, how can i do that? My current statement which is not working are as follows:

`UPDATE PricePlan SET Price='" + GuestInput.Text + "' WHERE PricePlanName = 'Guest' THEN Price='" + MemberInput.Text + "' WHERE PricePlanName = 'Member'`

Comment: please lookup 'SQL Injection" and parameterised queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work...you make have to modify it a little bit

```
"UPDATE PricePlan 
       SET price =
                 IIf(PricePlanName = 'Guest',"+ GuestInput.Text + ",
                   IIf(PricePlanName = 'Member',"+ MemberInput +"))"
```

Comment: received the following error:
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN (PricePlanName = 'Guest') THEN '3.00' WHEN (PricePlanName = 'Member' THEN '2.00' END'

Comment: @pacgeco IFF is synonymous to case in ms access...try now

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis after 'member'. Try fixing it or just remove every paranthesis, in this case are unnecesary